# CSS - Masonry image layout changing without notice

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, css-selectors

I'm building a section for a website using css masonry. I've used it in a couple of other sections and it works fine so I've used similar code for this section. When I use one particular image I get this layout (which is what I want) -

[image: Equal size image layout]

However, when I use a different image for each `.brick` element I get this layout style, which is more traditional for masonry but not the one I want for this section -

[Masonry image layout](http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1507579116/Screen_Shot_2017-10-09_at_20.49.41_z6csxb.png)

Why would something as simple as the change of an image file change the layout of a whole section? I've tried to review the code and gone over it again and again but I'm struggling because it changes only when I change the image file. Here's my code -

**index.html**

```
<section>
     <div class="staff">
                    <div class="masonry">            
                        <div class="brick">  
                                <img src="images/advertising.jpg"> 
                            <div class="details">     
                                <span id="info">  
                                    <h3>Acacia Schticter</h3>  
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>  
                                </span> 
                            </div>     
                        </div>

                           <div class="brick">  
                                <img src="images/graphic_design.jpg">  
                                <div class="details">     
                                <span id="info">  
                                    <h3>Catalina Tapia</h3>  
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>  
                                </span> 
                            </div>     
                            </div>

                            <div class="brick">  
                                <img src="images/brand_identity.jpg">  
                                <div class="details">     
                                <span id="info">  
                                    <h3>Acacia Schticter</h3>  
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>  
                                </span> 
                            </div>     
                        </div>

                        <div class="brick">  
                                  <img src="images/brand_guide.jpg">  
                            <div class="details">     
                                <span id="info">  
                                    <h3>Catalina Tapia</h3>  
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>  
                                </span> 
                            </div>     
                        </div>
                        <div class="brick">  
                                <img src="images/print.jpg"> 
                            <div class="details">     
                                <span id="info">  
                                    <h3>Acacia Schticter</h3>  
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>  
                                </span> 
                            </div>     
                        </div>

                           <div class="brick">  
                                <img src="images/creative_direction.jpg">  
                                <div class="details">     
                                <span id="info">  
                                    <h3>Catalina Tapia</h3>  
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>  
                                </span> 
                            </div>     
                            </div>

                            <div class="brick">  
                                <img src="images/ed_design.jpg">  
                                <div class="details">     
                                <span id="info">  
                                    <h3>Acacia Schticter</h3>  
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>  
                                </span> 
                            </div>     
                        </div>

                        <div class="brick">  
                                  <img src="images/other_stuff.jpg">  
                            <div class="details">     
                                <span id="info">  
                                    <h3>Catalina Tapia</h3>  
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>  
                                </span> 
                            </div>     
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>                              

    </section>
```

**style.css**

```
/* staff brick info */

.staff .details {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .7s ease;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

.brick:hover .details {
  opacity: 4;
}


.staff .details #info {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  top: 10%;
  padding: 15px;
}

.staff #info p {
  font-weight: lighter;
}



.brick:hover h2 {
  opacity: 0;
}



.masonry { /* Masonry container */
    column-count: 4;

}


.brick img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
}

body {

    font-family: 'Gotham-Light', sans-serif !important;
    margin: 0;
    background: #fff;
}

.wrapper {
    width: auto;
    margin: 3em;
}

.staff {

  width: auto;
  margin: 3em;
}

.masonry {
    margin: 1.5em 0;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;
    column-gap: 1.5em;
    font-size: .85em;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.brick {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    width: auto;
    opacity: .99;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;  
    overflow: hidden;  
    box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
}


/* text hover effect */ 

.brick:before {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%);

  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition-property: top, opacity;
  transition-property: top, opacity;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
          transition-duration: 0.3s;
}


 .brick img {
   position: relative; 
    left: 0;  
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}


.brick .details span {

  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition-property: top, opacity;
  transition-property: top, opacity;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
          transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
          transition-delay: 0s;
}


 .brick .details #info {
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.brick:focus:before,
  .brick:focus span, .brick:hover:before,
 .brick:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
}


 .brick:focus #info, .brick:hover #info {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s;
          transition-delay: 0.25s;
}
```

I want the layout to look identical to the first layout - all image elements exactly the same. I want to use the .masonry class as it works fine in other sections of the website and for RWD/ media queries.

Comment: Because the image dimensions differ.

Comment: @Roberrrt Is there a way to fix this in the CSS ?

Comment: Add a max-width and max-height that are identical to the `.brick img` rule (the one with the 100% height + width already). It's impractical for responsive stuff, but it does solve you issue.

Comment: @Roberrrt So will it just break when I change the screen size anyway?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44377343/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B This is great - thanks for sending this through. I'm having a doodle with it now. I understand the rules for rows but how do i set the columns to 4 equal lengths like above? I've set the minmax() to 25% but its still setting it to 3 grid-columns.

Comment: `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr)`

Comment: @Roberrrt Hi, I've set the grid up for my images as per Michael's link but the images still stretch/squash. Should I just re-set the dimensions in (e.g)picmonkey ? (They're quite large at the moment).